# Single App scalability Django

Tags: django, scalability

I find a common theme upon my research of using apps in django that "if you want to reuse a function in another project, create an app for it". I do not plan on creating any other projects in the future. However, I do plan on scaling my project at some point (to multiple cities and/or regions).

I have come to my own conclusion that I do not like bouncing from folder to folder for multiple apps in my project and I like the freedom of naming things in a way that is comprehensive to me (do not plan on using other peoples sources - I understand this requires more time and effort on my part). I also find it easier to look at things in one place, but this leaves me with a large amount of code in my single app.

1. Is there any significant performance advantages/disadvantages to using a single app?
2. In terms of scaling with my data storing in the future (if lucky enough to have this problem), will using a single app cause complexity of where I send my data?
3. Would using a single app be harder to test than doing multiple apps?

Comment: Technically, there is no performance difference of using multiple apps versus one single app for everything. However, if you plan to incorporate other developers or modify your code in the future, you are making it more difficult by only using one app. It's common practice to separate the methodology into separate apps the same way you separate functions for organizational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Every framework is built for a purpose and it is important to understand the psychology behind it. Django is is built based on the app mentality, it divides the project into multiple apps. It is built on  Unix philosophy of “Do one thing and do it well.”

1)There is no significant performance issues when you maintain a single app.

2)Yes, as your app scales up  gradually you will really face issues in maintaining the code bases. Since there is no such demarcation for the responsibilities understanding the code and further development becomes tedious job.

3)Dividing project into apps gives you a fair idea of what has to be tested. Hence single app mentality affects Te
sting too....